# Pygame's sprite.collide_circle() missing several frames of head-on collision

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame

I've spent hours trying to figure why my collision detection was so crappy, with sprites visibly ovellaping for several frames, when I noticed the culprit could be pygame's detection callback `pygame.sprite.collide_circle()`.

I've stripped down the code and created a simple demo, and results were surprising: `collide_circle()` still returns `False` for several frames after its sibling `collide_rect()` correctly detects a collision and returns `True`.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame

RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

SCREEN_SIZE = (800, 600)
FPS = 60
BG_COLOR = BLUE

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color=WHITE, radius=10, position=[], velocity=[]):
        super(Ball, self).__init__()

        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        self.position = list(position) or [0, 0]
        self.velocity = list(velocity) or [0, 0]
        self.bounds = (screen.get_size()[0] - self.radius,
                       screen.get_size()[1] - self.radius)

        self.image = pygame.Surface(2*[self.radius*2])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, 2*(self.radius,), self.radius)

    def update(self, dt=1./FPS):
        super(Ball, self).update()

        for i in [0, 1]:
            self.position[i] += self.velocity[i] * dt

            if self.position[i] < self.radius:
                self.position[i] = self.radius
                self.velocity[i] *= -1

            elif self.position[i] > self.bounds[i]:
                self.position[i] = self.bounds[i]
                self.velocity[i] *= -1

        self.rect.center = self.position


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill(BG_COLOR)
screen.blit(background, (0,0))

balls = pygame.sprite.Group()
balls.add(Ball(color=RED,   radius=100, position=[  0, 300], velocity=[ 100, 0]))
balls.add(Ball(color=GREEN, radius=100, position=[700, 300], velocity=[-100, 0]))

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT or
            event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            done = True

    balls.update()
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(*balls):
        collision = pygame.sprite.collide_circle(*balls)
        print collision
        if collision:
            for ball in balls:
                ball.velocity[0] *= -1

    balls.clear(screen, background)
    balls.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

And the output:

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

That's **17** frames of overlap before `collide_circle()` realizes that hey, there's a collision there! Even at 60 FPS that's huge.

The balls are almost halfway through each other, and this behavior seems to be velocity independent: if I change the balls' speed or the FPS, the visual result (halfway overlap) remains, but for fewer frames.

So, my question is: is this a pygame bug? Or did I completely misunderstood how detection works?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but did you consider doing an AABB/rectangle collision check first and *then* using `collide_circle` if there's a positive result?

Comment: @ashes999 That was my initial idea, but the problem is in this demo the circles are colliding head-on horizontally, so results from `collide_rect()` and `collide_circle()` should be the same. All those `False` are *not* false positives, and `collide_circle()` should be able to detect them.

Comment: @ashes999 also, note that I *am* using rectangle collision first! I'm only printing the cases that pass the test `if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(*balls):`

Comment: did you test if collision is true by finding the distance between the circles and if the sum of there radii is more than the distance, they are colliding?

Comment: @Serial yes, that's what I ended up doing myself, and it worked great, but isn't that what `pygame.sprite.collide_circle()` is supposed to do?

Comment: @MestreLion Not sure, I tried to find the source code for it but couldnt

Comment: @Serial https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame , and documentation on `collide_circle()` is http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle

Comment: @MestreLion Yeah I found the source, that's odd, Im not sure whats causing the lag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of PyGame were you using? An issue seems to have been fixed at some point between 1.9.1 and 1.9.2a concerning collide_circle() (see [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/commits/ac39f260d402748344ef1465c665a618fa623747) for fix diff).

It might be worth it to try 1.9.2a if possible (download/source [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads)), which I believe isn't actually up on pygame.org. If you're on Linux or OS X you'll have to build 1.9.2a from source.

Comment: I'm using `1.9.1release+dfsg-5`, the one that ships with Ubuntu 12.04. It's weird that 1.9.2 isn't packaged yet in Debian/Ubuntu, considering it was released in 2012. And thanks a lot for the links!

Comment: I've just found a Debian bug report with the same problem, and the suggested fix is included in the diff you posted, so it seems that issue was indeed fixed in 1.9.2. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=681975